# Google sign in with hard-coded account

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have developed a flutter app for uploading files to google drive. When I sign in with "google_sign_in" plugin it asks for google account interactively. Is there a way to login with a hard-coded google account or service account api key?

Comment: Signin is open id connect, service accounts are Oauth2. its two different things.   A user signs in.   service accounts are just used for server to server comunication.

Comment: Is there a way use google drive with hard-coded credentials?

Comment: That depends upon what you are doing.  If you are accessing a single drive account that you control then you should consider using a service account.    However if this is a plugin that users are going to be using then you need to use Oauth2 and authorize the user.

Comment: So I can login with a service account and make google drive api calls on my own drive account right?

Comment: That depends on if you have a google workspace account if its a domain account then yes you can set up domain wide delegation.   If its not then you can share directories and files with the service account and then it will be able to access them